# Indicator Keylock for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10

I am trying to install Indicator Keylock for Ubuntu 17.10, but when adding the repository I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsbarnes/indicator-keylock/ubuntu/' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Anyone could help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This means, that [PPA does not have packages for artful](https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-keylock).

Just remove this PPA and install package from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=indicator-keylock) with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```